# How to recognise Successful Swipe on the text not UItextView

Tags: objective-c, text, ios7, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

I want to recognize the **swipe gesture** on the **Text** presented on the **UItextview**.

If I have **"Enter your text"** in the **UITextView**

I want to recognise the swipe for "Enter your text" 
and also I want to recognise it separately for each word
like

**"Enter"** If i do swipe on text **Enter**

**"your"**  If i do swipe on text **your**

I didn't find anything related in internet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this. UITextView has a layoutManager property which gives you lots of extra access to the string metrics.

When you recognise a swipe on the UITextView get the location of the touch in the view:

```
- (void)swipe:(UISwipeGestureRecogniser *)recogniser {
    CGPoint point = [recogniser locationInView:textView];
}
```

After you have the point, you can ask the layout manager for the index in the string where that point is. Check out the docs on NSLayoutManager... Perhaps try:

```
int index = [textView.layoutManager characterIndexForPoint:point inTextContainer:textView.textContainer fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:NULL];
```

The you can use some basic string manipulation on the string in the text view to determine the word that that index is at...

Let me know if you need any more help on this, have spent a lot of time wrestling with CoreText and text layouts! :)

Edit: Here's a view controller implementation of this working:

```
@implementation MyViewController

#pragma mark - View Lifecycle Methods

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Create a swipe gesture recogniser
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recogniser = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipe:)];
    recogniser.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight; // add other directions if needed
    // Add the swipe gesture recogniser to the text view
    [self.textView addGestureRecognizer:recogniser];
}

#pragma mark - Action Methods

- (void)swipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recogniser {
    // Get the location of the gesture recogniser in the text view
    CGPoint point = [recogniser locationInView:self.textView];
    // Get the character index of the swipe
    NSUInteger index = [self.textView.layoutManager characterIndexForPoint:point inTextContainer:self.textView.textContainer fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:NULL];
    // Get the word at the giver index
    NSString *word = [self getWordAtIndex:index fromString:self.textView.text];
    NSLog(@"Swiped on word: %@", word);
}

#pragma mark - Helper Methods

- (NSString *)getWordAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index fromString:(NSString *)string {
    __block NSString *word = nil;
    [string enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, string.length) options:NSStringEnumerationByWords usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
    if (NSLocationInRange(index, enclosingRange)) {
        word = substring;
        *stop = YES;
    }}];
    return word;
}

@end
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea you could do all that :)

Comment: @George Thanks for the reply.Is is possible to get the text presented in the view using points

Comment: @George How can I use point to get the string presented there

Comment: @iCoder The method shown at the bottom should take the point and from it give you the character index in the string where the point was. Text view string: "Hello world", index: 6, user swiped on "w". When I get the chance this afternoon I will write you some sample code to show you how it works!

Comment: @iCoder, I have added a functional implementation of a view controller that does what you are looking for. Sorry it took so long! Hope this is still of some use to you?